# composer.phar shows ??? error

Tags: php, composer-php

When I am using composer it shows

```
$ sudo php composer.phar update
 ???
```

Before that

I can use this command as usual with Mountain-Lion pre-installed php.

However I want to use new php because I need to include ext-mcrypt.

So I installed new php by

```
brew install mcrypt php53-mcrypt
```

then change filename

```
mv /usr/bin/php /usr/bin/php.back
```

and use /usr/local/bin/php ( homebrew installed this)

php -v shows correctly and other php scripts are working fine.

DO you think what the problem of my composer.phar??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have detect_unicode enabled in your php.ini. I don't know how you got the composer.phar, but if you used the installer we provide it would have told you to disable this as it causes bugs with phar files.

Comment: I added 'detect_unicode = Off' in php.ini,then it works!! thanks!